# Can't Send Email through PHP on localhost using Gmail account

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

On **30 May 2022** *Google* changed "Less secure apps" settings and it's no longer available.

[Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Due to which I'm not able to send Email on localhost using PHP.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Well, the link you've posted suggests several solutions - did you try any of them? The most obvious (and probably simplest) one is to use the App Password functionality.

Comment: A good question would include some code and ask for specific advice about a problem.  This question is very broad.  You could give one of those methods a try and then ask for help with a specific problem if you struggle to complete the integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume you are connecting to Gmail via the smtp server.

If you are currently using the actual password for the gmail account you are connecting to. The the best thing to do would be to try creating an apps password and using that.

[Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'APPsPassword';                               //New apps password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->Port       = 465;
```

Another option would be to switch to [Xoauth](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) or switching to the Gmail api again using Oauth2.

```
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "[Redacted]@gmail.com";
$mail->oauthClientId = "[Redacted]";
$mail->oauthClientSecret = "[Redacted]";
$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "[Redacted]";
```